# Is there a R function which would return a predefined min & max value if the computed value exceeds the range?

Tags: javascript, r, if-statement, simplify

I have a formula. When r calculates the value, if the result is between 0 and 1, the function should return the computed value. But, if it is below 0, the function should return 0, and if it is above 1, the function should return 1.

Is there an efficient way to do it without using the if function?

I found a javascript code that does what I want to do in R. Here it is:

```
clip = (a, b, t) => Math.min(Math.max(t, a), b)
```

Comment: please translate `x <- y - z` in english

Comment: `pmin(pmax(t, a), b)` does the work for t vectors..

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, you could guard with `Math.min` and `Math.max` with lower and upper bound.

```js
const
    x = (y, z) => Math.max(Math.min(y - z, 1), 0);

console.log(x(1, 2));   // 0
console.log(x(2, 0));   // 1
console.log(x(1, 0.5)); // 0.5
```

Comment: User ask about "R" language not js

Comment: right. question is tagged with [javascript] and i assume this approach should work with R as well.